# Why is my masonry not layout properly when it's loading images?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using masonry layout by desandro and It's working fine. Though when it's loading the images, the layout is out. It rearranges itself after all images are loaded but all stack up together when loading.

Flickr seems to be the one that I'm aiming for the layout. On flickr photostream, the tiles are already layout with gray colored background and it loads its images there directly. How can I achieve something like this?

Here's the script that I'm using:

```
 var $container = $('#wall');

 $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
 $container.masonry({
 "columnWidth": ".grid-sizer",
 "gutter": ".gutter-sizer",
 "itemSelector" : '.item'
 });
});
```

It's important to note also that I'm using infinite loading by Paul on a WordPress theme that I'm implementing for my blog.

```
$container.infinitescroll({
navSelector : '.pagination ', // selector for the paged navigation
nextSelector : '.next.page-numbers', // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
itemSelector : '.item', // selector for all items you'll retrieve
loading: {
msg: null,
msgText: "<small>loading content...",
finishedMsg: "<small>End of line.</small>",
speed: 'fast',
img: 'http://i.imgur.com/Ky3zbSs.gif'
}
},
// trigger Masonry as a callback
function( newElements ) {
// hide new items while they are loading
var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
// ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
$newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
// show elems now they're ready
$newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
$container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
});
}
);
```

Comment: Try `$container.masonry('layout');` after `$container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );`.

Comment: That will only load the masonry layout after the the infinite scrolling which I don't have a problem with. When infinite loading loads contents, the layout is OK. What I want to do is when it's loading images. When it's loading images at first landing, the layout is off. It only arranges itself after the images have been loaded.